# `find_theorems` in the AFP

Tags: isabelle

How can I use the `find_theorems` mechanism to search the whole Archive of Formal Proofs (AFP)?

I have downloaded the archive to my machine, and I am able to import theories from it. For instance, if I write `imports Kleene_Algebra.Kleene_Algebra_Models` then all the theorems in that theory are successfully made available to me. But if I then type `find_theorems <expression>`, I only get search results from the specific theory I imported. What if I want to search the whole archive? For instance, perhaps somebody has proved a theorem that is useful to me, but I don't know what they called their theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_theorems` only works with the loaded theories. You can use any text search tool if you have an idea of the theorem name. On macOS, the Splotlight Search (cmd + space) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To put it plain and simple, you can't, unless you import the entirety of the AFP into your theory (which probably won't work).

I'm unsure whether someone is currently working on making what you want happen.

Comment: Larry Paulson and his team of the ALEXANDRIA project are working aim to, among other things, do just that. They're still at the very beginning though.